# Why doesn't voltage on one terminal of a capacitor matter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, vlsi, voltage-source

In the context of characterizing the load driven by an inverter by an effective capacitance, my textbook (*CMOS VLSI Design: A Circuits and Systems Perspective*, 4th edition, by Weste and Harris) gives the following explanation:

[image]

I am in particular not able to follow the line which reads:

> It is also irrelevant whether the second terminal of each capacitor connects to ground or power because both are constant supplies, so for the sake of simplicity, we can draw all of the capacitors as if they are connected to ground.

Why should it be irrelevant if a capacitor with one terminal connected to node B has its other terminal connected to GND or to VDD? This seems on the face of it to make a great difference.

Comment: Note that this applies to AC only.   The DC power supply is a short circuit for AC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capacitor interacts with the remainder of the circuit through the current that enters/leaves its terminal as well as the *time derivative* of the voltage across it:

$$ I = C \frac{dV}{dt} $$

Changing the voltage across the cap by a constant value (i.e. by attaching the other end directly to some other DC supply) does not change dV/dt.

This is *analogous* (not truly the same) to how all (assumed-ideal) power rails may be considered ground in a small-signal model.

Comment: Sure, but the boundary condition to the DE is completely different depending on which node voltage is connected to the other terminal of the capacitor (other than B), no?

Comment: I don't follow your analogy to small-signal analysis given that that follows from superposition/linearization of the circuit. Nothing to do with the derivative in particular (though the derivative is also linear). Just my sense though, I could be wrong.

Comment: @EE18 the observable quantities that matter to someone analyzing the circuit behavior, i.e. the voltage and the current, are unchanged under that specific change of the boundary condition. The remark about linearization requires one more step — you can do that same superposition with the DC excitation on the cap's terminal and nothing else, superimposed on the response to all the other excitations with the cap grounded — and you will likewise see that the first of those two doesn't change the behavior of the circuit or its dynamics.

Comment: ... at most, it means that for the same initial condition of observable voltages/currents elsewhere in the circuit, the initial condition for the capacitor's voltage changes by the same magnitude, but again, this doesn't change any of the actual dynamics or observable quantities (circuit time constant, voltage at B, currents entering/exiting node B through various branches, etc)

Comment: I am still not quite sure I follow. I can't argue by superposition here since the circuit is nonlinear? As for your other comment, I suppose I can take "unchanged under that specific change of the boundary condition" (and I suppose *specific* does a lot of work here?) on faith, but if you get the chance an example or mathematical explication of that claim would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The superposition is meant to be a conceptual aid but probably missed the mark if taken too literally. I'll edit it when I'm at a PC rather than phone. The word *specific* refers to the same assumption that you made - that this extra capacitor voltage is a DC voltage. If you applied some changing voltage on that other terminal, the result would obviously be different. The main point is still about observable quantities - changing that DC offset doesn't change the actual current that enters or leaves the capacitor - that current is a consequence of the derivative of the cap voltage.

Comment: As for a more explicit mathematical justification: you have your set of KCL equations at the node the capacitor interacts with, a set of KCL/KVL equations for unrelated nodes, branch equations for unrelated branches, and the branch equation for the capacitor and the DC voltage offset on the first terminal. Changing that offset doesn't change the current entering or exiting the cap as a function of the time dependent voltage applied to the second terminal of the cap, and that current as a function of voltage is the only way that cap interacts. No changes to other currents, voltages, or dynamics

Comment: @EE18  the for-dummies explanation:  all this only applies to AC.  And for AC, the power supply is a short circuit (or at worst a fraction of an ohm.)   For AC, Vdd is laready connected to ground.  The "huge difference" only appears for signals at DC (and perhaps deep ELF, if 10pF and 10^11 ohms were involved.)

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what the absolute voltage over a capacitor is, as changing the voltage by a given amount needs the same given amount of charge.

For example, charging a capacitance from 0V to 1V takes equal amount of current for an equal amount of time to move equal amount of charge, than charging the same capacitance from 1000V to 1001V.

Likewise, in a CMOS circuit, it does not matter if you have a node with 10pF capacitance to ground, as it's the same amount of capacitance than having 5pF to ground and 5pF to supply. To charge a node from 0V to 5V requires changing either voltage of one 10pF cap by 5V, or changing voltages of two 5pF caps by 5V.

If it helps, imagine the CMOS circuit is powered by an ideal power supply, so it has zero output impedance between ground and supply nodes, so in small signal terms, both the capacitance to ground and to supply are in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to remember once and for all that both the voltage source (in general) and the capacitor (only for quick changes) are *voltage stabilizers*. Therefore, a network of two such elements connected in series is also a voltage stabilizer (for quick changes).

So (for fast changes) it does not matter whether a capacitor is connected directly to ground or through a voltage source (power supply). In either case, its voltage will not change when the input voltage changes rapidly, and the current will change as if nothing is connected in the circuit.